# Acceder a una imagen externa RichFaces

Tags: java, jsp, richfaces

Tengo un problema gigante en mi trabajo jeje.

Resulta que trabajamos con RichFaces, JSP, Java.
Debo de acceder y mostrar en JSP una imagen que esta alojada en la raiz del disco duro, pero no logro encontrar la manera de colocar la ruta correcta y no me la muestra.

Estoy usando la etiqueta "graphicImage" en la cual coloco la ruta donde esta la imagen "value="C:/mnt/SoftwareAndDeve/SOFT/IMAGES/Frases.png" " pero esto no funciona y he intentado de todo con esta ruta. Le quito el C:/ o colocando ... antes, de todo y aun no me muestra la imagen.

Requiero esto ya que es una imagen que se debe cambiar constantemente y si no hago esto, habria que montar version a produccion constantemente.

Espero hacerme entender y perdon mi poco conocimiento al respecto.

Agradezco su ayuda :D

Answer (score 1):

Lo más fácil sería agregar la carpeta como un "contexto virtual" del servletcontainer que está utilizando. En Tomcat, se trata de agregar una novedad `<Context>` al `server.xml`

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/images" path="/images" />
```

y en Glassfish es una cuestión de agregar una `alternatedocroot` a la `glassfish-web.xml`

```
<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/images/* dir=/path/to" />
```

Consulte la documentación del servletcontainer para más detalles. En última instancia, deben ser accesibles mediante una URL normal para que pueda usar, por ejemplo:

```
<p:graphicImage value="/images/#{image.imageName}" />
```

Otras formas incluyen el uso de [PrimeFaces `StreamedContent` API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362786/showing-a-dynamic-image-that-depends-on-a-request-parameter/10363457#10363457) o homegrowing a servlet. (Traducir).

**Vea también (Traducir):**

- [La forma más simple de servir datos estáticos desde fuera del
  servidor de aplicaciones en una aplicación web
  Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1812356/8933039)
- [Cargue imágenes desde fuera de la carpeta webapps / webcontext / deploy con la etiqueta `<h: graphicImage>` o `<img>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4543951/8933039)